# How to achieve the marquee effect through js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

At present, I need to make a scrolling marquee effect in the project, but I encountered two problems during the production process. I don’t know the reason?
I hope everyone can help me look at the code, or provide some more Good wording!

Question one
hopes that when the marquee scrolls up, each one can stay for one second, and then continue to scroll!
But currently it will scroll two consecutively, and then stop at a strange place, not in the middle of the block .

Question 2:
I hope that the marquee effect needs to be activated only when there are two paragraphs of text. If there is only one paragraph, the marquee effect will not be used.

Since I have just learned JavaScript and I am not very familiar with it, I hope I can get your help, thank you!

```js
function slideLine(box,stf,delay,speed,h)
{
    var slideBox = document.getElementById(box);
    var delay = delay||1000,speed = speed||20,h = h||40;
    var tid = null,pause = false;
    var s = function(){tid=setInterval(slide, speed);}
    var slide = function(){
        if(pause) return;
        slideBox.scrollTop += 1;
        if(slideBox.scrollTop%h == 0){
        clearInterval(tid);
        slideBox.appendChild(slideBox.getElementsByTagName(stf)[0]);
        slideBox.scrollTop = 0;
        setTimeout(s, delay);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(s, delay);
}
slideLine('kanban_info','p',1000,25,40);
```

```css
.kanban {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 278px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
}
.kanban .kenban_wrap {
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="kanban">
  <div class="kenban_wrap" id='kanban_info'>
      <p class="kanban_info">hello</p>
      <p class="kanban_info">world</p>       
      <p class="kanban_info">javascript</p>     
      <p class="kanban_info">HTML</p>
      <p class="kanban_info">CSS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just had a quick look on Codepen to see if some people had found a nice solution and perhaps [this one could help](https://codepen.io/sakueinozomi/pen/ZEWNjKr) you ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, this effect is similar to what I want!
But how to do it if there is only one dIV in HTML, then marquee effect is not run?

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/yLoQxEX?editors=1010

Comment: I took the example and put the `<p>` paragraphs inside. Also renamed the class to `marquee_content` to be clearer. This would be the result: https://codepen.io/patacra/pen/JjyemgG

Comment: Thank you for the example!
But maybe I did not clarify my question, because I hope that when there is only one text label in marquee_content, the effect of the marquee will stop! The
marquee will only run when there are more than two labels, but I Do not know what to do?